# *const *__w64 ' to 'IDocument **' errors

Tags: visual-c++

I am trying to build code in vs2005. I dont why I am getting this type of error many times.

error C2664: 'ATL::_CopyInterface::copy' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'IDocument *const *__w64 ' to 'IDocument **'

Same code compiles well on XP with vs2005.
But throwing above error on win7 with 2005.

Please help.

Comment: Please don't expect us to reverse-engineer your code from an error message.  Post a snippet that generates this error and document the build settings you used.  Clearly something related to 64-bit code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does *not* sound like a runtime problem with the OS.  It sounds like your VS2005 defaults to 32-bit compiles when you installed it on XP ... but your VS2005 defaults to 64-bit compiles when you installed it on Win7 (64-bit Win7, I'm guessing?)

ANYWAY:
Just recompile and explicitly specify 32-bit, on both hosts:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h2k70f3s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241064%28v=vs.80%29.aspx
- [Using Visual Studio 2005 (32bit) on a Windows 7 64bit machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487567/using-visual-studio-2005-32bit-on-a-windows-7-64bit-machine)